# Android Device Monitor

Tags: java, android, jvm

When trying to access android device monitor on android studio, and I keep getting the error message[image]

Even though I added the new JDK to my project I still keep getting this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you can do:

1) Set your Java Path
JAVA_HOME => C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21
path => C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\bin

2) Check if your Jre path is correct
To Check:
Go to File > Project Structure > SDK Location:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMuqy.png)

3) There're 2 exe file in android-studio\bin one for 32-bit (**studio.exe**) and other for 64-bit (**studio64.exe**). Make sure you're opening the executable file which matches your Java Version.

If above methods doesn't work, then you can:

4) Try to reinstall JDK and JRE again

5) Try to reinstall the Studio again

Comment: Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home

Comment: Is where I have my JDK

Answer (score -1):

Right click on android studio icon and choose run as administrator. This will probably solve the issue.

Comment: I am using a mac